# ¿Stack Overflow en español tendrá apartado de trabajo?

Tags: discusión

De vez en cuando miro el apartado Job de https://stackoverflow.com/jobs mi pregunta es:

¿existirá en el futuro un apartado similar en Stack Overflow en español?